# Hide Unnecessary Info in SE Chat

Tags: script, chat

### Hide Unnecessary or Cluttering Information in the Sidebar of an SE Chatroom

---

#### Description

A small userscript to help avoid clutter on the sidebar of any Stack Exchange chat room.

- The chat room will load without showing the chat room's info or the present users in the chat room
- There will be buttons that say "Show Info" or "Show Users", and when they are clicked on, the chat room's info or the present users will be shown
- When the chat room's info or present users are visible, there will be buttons saying "Hide Info" and "Hide Users", and those will hide the chat room's info or present users

---

This userscript supports Chrome and should support all other browsers.

---

#### Code and Download

You can view the code for this userscript on [Github](https://github.com/michaelpri10/Hide-Unnecessary-Info-in-SE-Chat) or download it [here](https://github.com/michaelpri10/Hide-Unnecessary-Info-in-SE-Chat/raw/master/hide_info.user.js).